# how to change google map API's My Location button postion in flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I'm using bellow widget,I want to change MyLocation button get to bottom position in my map view

```
GoogleMap(

                  onMapCreated: onMapCreated,

              options: GoogleMapOptions(


                    myLocationEnabled :true, 
                    mapType: MapType.hybrid,

                  cameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(6.8814635,79.8876697),
                    zoom: 15.0,),
                  ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the solution. I create FAB button to change My Location button

```
GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _currentLocation,
        label: Text('My Location'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
      ),
    );
  }
```

also, set the `_currentLocation` method to call my location

```
void _currentLocation() async {
   final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
   LocationData currentLocation;
   var location = new Location();
   try {
     currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
     } on Exception {
       currentLocation = null;
       }

    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        bearing: 0,
        target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
        zoom: 17.0,
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: pressing on FAB gives you the current location on the screen, but does it take to your current location?

Comment: Yes. It will.
The code with animateCamera is for it

Comment: I couldn't find LocationData class, which is it from?

Comment: @funder7 install the location package to get that https://pub.dev/packages/location/install

Comment: This works but it's very slow, I solved it by always updating location using location.onLocationChanged.listen((event) { myLocation = event; });  instead of using myLocation = location.getLocation(); every time I push the button

Comment: Excellent workaround, I wish they exposed more methods from the SDK. For instance, the button click event could be subscribed to on Android: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener

Answer (score 22):

Use **padding** property of GoogleMap widget

```
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GoogleMap(
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: _center,
        zoom: 11.0,
      ),
      mapType: _currentMapType,
      markers: _markers,
      onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0,),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image 1: without padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9xZj.jpg)

[image 2: with padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHSZ1.jpg)

Comment: Although this does move the button, it will also move the center of the map and therefore pressing the button will probably not do expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding on top!
in my case;

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 155.0),
```

Comment: see @mauriii's comment above.